Flutter styled toast not showing toast in Release mode but working in debug mode
Here the package used flutter_styled_toast: ^2.2.1
Method used to show toast.
Perfectly working in debug mode, but toast not appearing in Release Mode.
showToast(
      msg,
      context: context,
      position: position,
      backgroundColor:
          CustomTheme.isLightTheme(context) ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
      textStyle: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 14.sp,
        color: CustomTheme.isLightTheme(context) ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
      ),
    );


Suggestions needed to fix this.
